# Traditional ASP.NET application in subdirectory of an MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Windows Server 2003, IIS6.

We're trying to deploy a non-MVC ASP.NET web application as a subdirectory of an MVC application.

However the ASP.NET application in the subdirectory is failing with the message "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." which is bizarre because it's not an MVC application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wound up not solving this problem, because we ran into a different but related problem. Since the paths in our MVC application do not use file extensions, we had to install a wildcard mapping, which we believed would prevent the subdirectory website from functioning.

So we punted and moved the sub-application to a subdomain and added a redirect for that subdirectory in the parent application's routes.

Answer (score 0):

Need more information:

1. Is the child (sub-folder) ASP.NET web application running in its own IIS Application, or in the parent's IIS Application?
2. Where is `System.Web.Mvc.dll` deployed?

If #1 is false (i.e. same IIS Application) then the requirement for `System.Web.Mvc` is being inherited from the parent `web.config`.

Comment: 1. It's in its own application. We tried setting the folder as an application, and also moving the folder to a separate path and creating a virtual directory.

2. It's installed on the server, so it's in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the same error for a different assembly in a very similar situation:

- IIS 8.5
- a site running an ASP.NET MVC application
- a virtual application underneath it, called `app`, in our case also an MVC app

In our case, though, the virtual application failed to load because `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll` version `3.0.0.0` could not be loaded. We actually had version `3.0.1.0` sitting there but even with an *assembly redirect* in the `web.config` this would not help. It was the root application that was using version `3.0.0.0`.

Running the virtual application underneath an *empty site* (simply pointing to an empty folder) worked, though. Also, running it as its own site worked as well.

Since I couldn't get the error fixed with the given setup, I came up with a different **solution**: **hosting the root app as a virtual application**, as well.

Now, this implied running inside a virtual folder, let's call it `w`. The missing part in the puzzle was now a **rewrite rule** to map the site root to that virtual folder `w`. I put this rule into a new `web.config` file in the empty site root folder. This is what it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite / to /w" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/w" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite rest to /w/rest" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(/.*)$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/w{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(^w$|^w/)|(^app/)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

As you can see, it's actually two rewrite rule because I couldn't quite get it to work with only one. In the second rule you can see that I exclude `app` from rewriting because that's where my other application lives.

Here's what we have:

- requests for `www.mydomain.com` get rewritten to `www.mydomain.com/w` and subsequently processed by our first virtual application `w` which used to be our root application
- requests for `www.mydomain.com/app` are handled by our virtual application `app` as expected

I'm currently still fighting with some static file paths not being properly rewritten, but I expect to get this fixed soon.